# It's a compilation in the student list class, but it's not aligned

Tags: java, sorting

```
public void sortById() {
    int i, j, min;
    for(i = 0 ; i < number - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < number; j++) {
            if (StudentList[j].getId() < StudentList[min].getId()) {
                min = j;
            }
            swap(StudentList[min].getId(), StudentList[i].getId());
        }
    }
}

public void swap(StudentList std1, StudentList std2) {
    Student st = new Student(0,"",0);
    st = std1;
    std1 = std2;
    std2 = st;
}
```

If I compile the code above, there is no error and an exception, and it comes out unaligned, so how do you solve it?

Comment: what does that means "it comes out unaligned"?

Comment: Why are you assigning a Student object to a StudentList object? Does Java not do type checking? Plus you're passing the ID of the student object not the object itself so swap should throw an error

Comment: I don't see how JavaScript is relevant here.

Comment: swaping local varaibles (what you do in the `swap`method) does not do the same thing as swaping array'se elements

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you mean by "it comes out unaligned", but you are probably running into problems because you are not actually swapping anything in your `swap` method.

Instead if passing the objects into the method, you need to pass the indexes of those objects, like this:

```
public void swap(int a, int b) {
    StudentList temp = studentList[a];
    studentList[a] = studentList[b];
    studentList[b] = temp;
}
```

And call the method this way:

```
swap(min, i);
```

Comment: To add some precision: OP's `swap`method only swap **local** variables `std1`and `std2`, not the references stored in the array

Comment: That's a better way to put it, thanks @jhamon for the correction.